# Attributes in the root template element of directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the simple directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
       label: '@',
       ngModel: '=',
       class: '@'
    },

    template: "<div><span>{{label}}</span><input class='{{class}}' type='text' ng-model='ngModel' /></div>"
}
```

Using:

```
<myDirective label="myLabelA myClassB" class="my-class" ng-model="myModel" />
```

In result looks like:

```
<div label="myLabelA myClassB" class="my-class" ng-model="myModel">
    <span>myLabel</span> 
     <input class="myLabelA myClassB" type="text" ng-model="myModel" />
</div>
```

Is there a way to eliminate the attributes from the root div element?

Comment: i have set transclude = false, but the problem remained

Comment: I think it's not possible. and why do you need to remove them?

Comment: otherwise, my div have extra css styles.

Comment: @feak don't hesitate to mention it. See updated answer.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think if we leave it, the DOM looks ugly, sorry for my perfectionism.

Comment: if you remove css class from directive template, styles will not be applied, and it's normal for elements to have attributes

Answer (score 1):

You can set `replace` to false, then HTML will contain original `my-directive` element and new element inside of it, without attributes of parent.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Vdw3YVMwzgElCFF7EGeM?p=preview

If you need to remove back-effects of existence DOM element - rename attribute `class` of directive, so browser will not apply it to parent element.

Comment: in this case, the original element remain in dom with all attributes..
`<myDirective label="myLabelA myClassB" class="my-class" ng-model="myModel" />`

Comment: @feak refresh answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove these attributes by providing a compile function to the directive that removes those attributes from the element:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            label: '@',
            ngModel: '=',
            class: '@'
        },
        template: "<div><span>{{label}}</span><input class='{{class}}' type='text' ng-model='ngModel' /></div>",
        compile: function ($element) {
            $element.removeAttr('label')
                    .removeAttr('class')
                    .removeAttr('ng-model');
        }
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9hB43/2/

regards